# gnome-terminal instantly closes after messing with the profile settings

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I am using Gnome Terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 and I modified the profile preferences, setting it to start with a custom command instead of the default. I can't remember what that custom command was, but now when I launch the terminal, it instantly closes.

Is there any way to change the profile preferences in terminal without having it open?

Comment: What command did you set it to, because I bet the 'command' is running and then terminating automatically, which is going to cause problems all the time.

Comment: This is being marked as "offtopic" in that it can't be reproduced nor can it be useful in the future.  The OP has commented in an answer that they fixed it themselves.  If the OP posts their 'solution' as an answer then I may remove that close vote, however it does not appear this question in the form it's in will be useful to future readers.

Comment: @ThomasW. it can trivially be reproduced e.g. by setting the default profile's 'Custom command' to `/bin/false`

Comment: @steeldriver but as it currently is in its current form, it's not relevant or useful to future readers.  As well, it could also be "Unclear" or "Too Broad", it could fall into *multiple* close reasons.

Comment: @ThomasW. I would concede that the *title* is unclear, however the body of the question seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @ThomasW. I'm leaving this open since, although we don't know the *exact* things the OP did there is enough information for the two answer below to answer the question and help someone else.

Comment: Well, the below answer will help! https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518443/336057

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate the `gnome-terminal` settings programmatically using `gconftool` e.g. to restore the settings of the default profile

1. open a plain `xterm` from the dash
2. execute `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default`

Answer (score 2):

Delete everything in `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/` folder. Profile preferences are stored there. In nautilus make sure you enable viewing hidden files and folders to actually find .gconf directory

Comment: Nevermind I got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named 'something.desktop' and add the following code.
If you are familiar with the commands on launching the 'something.desktop', it will list all the files in the home directory in a terminal.

And, make sure to make 'something.desktop' executable. Fro making any file executable the code is

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/something.desktop
```

Edit it with your own values

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=IPT
GenericName=IPT
Comment=IPT Desktop icon developed by Mritunjay
Categories=Network;Security;
X-KeepTerminal=true
Icon=/usr/img/ip.png
Exec=gnome-terminal --tab --title="List files" --command="bash -c '/home; ls; $SHELL'"

NoDisplay=true
```

I have answered it on [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518443/336057) also.

Comment: Yeah, it is my answer. Well, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a command that will open gnome-terminal with the settings you typed in a custom command in another terminal, after that it will open the gnome-terminal and then you can fix the wrong custom preferences commands.

1. Download an external terminal (**xterm** in my case)
2. Open xterm
3. Copy and paste the following command using the shortcut `shift+insert`

   **Command**:
   `gnome-terminal --tab --title="List files" --command="bash -c '/home; ls; $SHELL'"`

Answer (score 0):

Today, I encountered an issue with the preference settings in the GNOME Terminal. I mistakenly set a custom command, "cd /specifi," and whenever I attempted to open it, it didn't behave as expected. After consulting forums for a solution, I found that a simple restart resolved the issue.