# Terminal closing itself

Tags: command-line

I messed up and now terminal closing itself as soon as I open him.
I wanted that terminal execute command when it's starts, but I haven't noticed "when command exits" was "close terminal". Now it's closing itself as soon as I open it. How to fix? Reset terminal settings?

Comment: Sounds like [gnome-terminal instantly closes after messing with the profile settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594876/gnome-terminal-instantly-closes-after-messing-with-the-profile-settings)

Comment: Are you trying to run a command from like Alt+F2 command and then have the terminal stay open?  Something like `xterm -e 'ls'; bash` ?  Or `gnome-terminal - e 'ls'; bash` ?

Answer (score 0):

Open a tty (control-alt-f2) and see if you can login, edit the file with `vi` or `nano` and remove the line you added. (control-alt-f1 gets you back to the graphical interface) (control-alt-f7 if you use unity).

If a tty closes itself too use a live dvd session and edit the file from a live session.

Comment: what do you mean by editing file vi or nano?

Comment: I said "with".  You can edit text files on commandline with "vi" or "nano".

Answer (score 0):

Open xterm

Type this command:

```
gnome-terminal -e -ls
```

the bash shell (gnome-terminal) will be open (instead of closing), because it tries to execute another command than the other established in the profile configuration.

Change the profile configuration.